# REST API to, given a site URL, get the top level site of that URL (sharepoint 2010, 2013 and 2016)

Tags: rest, site-collection

I've got a sharepoint site with multiple site collections.

`/` site collection:

```
http://mysite/    <--- root site in `/` site collection
http://mysite/subsite1
http://mysite/subsite2
```

`/sitecol1` site collection:

```
http://mysite/sitecol1/   <-- root site in `/sitecol1` site collection
http://mysite/sitecol1/mysubsiteinsitecol1
http://mysite/sitecol1/mysubsiteinsitecol2
```

Using rest api, how can I given `http://mysite/sitecol1/mysubsiteinsitecol2` determine what root site colleciton it is from?

UPDATE:

Forgot to mention - I need this to work on SharePoint 2010, 2013 and 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use REST API to get to the root site. Try this below endpoint in your browser. Append this after your site URL -

`/_api/site/rootweb?$select=Title,ServerRelativeUrl,URL`

The URL value will give your root site collection

Comment: doesn't work on sharepoint 2010. works on sharepoint 2013 and 2016 however.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `_spPageContextInfo` object to get the URL making use of the `siteAbsoluteUrl` property as:

`var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl`

Another way to determine the site collection url is to make a JSOM call :

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var site = clientContext.get_site();
clientContext.load(site);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){ 
    console.log(site.get_url()); 
},
function(){
    console.log("something went wrong");
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSOM. but I'm sure that just comes down to REST calls when all is said and done?

Comment: yes internally its all REST calls. Just drop this code inside script tag and it should work

Comment: I'm on a linux machine with no access to the SharePoint instance. Can you please run this in your browser with devtools network tab enabled then send me the REST calls the browser made to get the info?

Comment: I have access to SPO only. The REST call in online will be different from OnPrem. Just paste the code in the browser console on a standard sharepoint page, it will work. Same goes for the `_spPageContextInfo`, just type that in console, it will give you the properties

Comment: here is what i got https://pastebin.com/x0zzKm7k
but when i try to make this call directly from postman, i get 401 error every time